# Is it possible to update to IE10 on windows phone 7 or 7.5?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-phone-7, internet-explorer-10, placeholder

Im wondering if it is possible to update your IE on windows phone 7 ?

Because im having a problem due showing the place holder of a form on IE9, its not supported on that version.

Im not a windows phone user so im asking you guys.

Is it possible to update IE9 to IE 10 on windows phone 7 or 7.5 ?

Comment: why was this closed as off topic??  The features of IE10 allow a web app that I maybe developing to attempt html5 or css3 for example, but only if the browser is of version 10 instead of 9.

Comment: I dont know actually. - @andrew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

Microsoft announced that even with the update to WP7.8 there will be only IE9 as IE10 uses hardware acceleration and the hardware of the WP7 devices don't support this acceleration.

Comment: So basicly only Windows Phone 8 supports IE 10 ?

Comment: Yes. WP8 will come with IE10.